# Creation of a Wikipedia tag

Tags: feature-request, tags

sorry to bother you for this little thing, but I would ask you if it is possible to create a "Wikipedia" tag.

I see [71 results](https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=wikipedia+is%3Aquestion) querying for Wikipedia in academia.SE questions.

I don't think it's gonna be easy for me to earn 300 rep soon, so I will directly ask here. If created, I can start using it for some of the existing questions. Thanks everyone.

Comment: As long as there are many other wiki websites and wikipedia is not the only website of this kind; I think that having a tag with a broader title like [wiki-websites] is more suitable than [wikipedia] for the Academia.

Comment: I respectfully disagree :-): Wikipedia is unique in his kind as the biggest crowdsourced encyclopedia online, and his used by half a billion users every month. The scale, the scope, the features (Neutral Point of View, no original research) make it different from other wikis. So a tag on his own is preferred, IMHO.

Comment: Also **Don't run, walk!** Having 71 results does not necessarily mean that the website needs such tag. It is so nice to have your proposal about such tag in meta, but; please don't hurry in such huge edit. Please give some time (about one or two days) to the users to see your post in meta, see for and against to your proposal, see what community thinks about your proposal and then decide to create such tag and do huge edits.

Comment: Thanks for this second advice. I'll keep it in mind (next time: if the tags should be removed, I'll do it myself. Sorry for the rush).

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent You should be criticizing me and not Aubrey.  I do, however, think we should have that tag.

Comment: @jakebeal I do appreciate your point of view, but I insist that if the users are even a hundred percent sure that a tag is needed on site; *if their proposal is brought on meta*, they should wait for some time to receive the feedback from other users. Also, as mentioned above; it should be proved that the tag is *needed* on the site, that amount of search results is *not* a good reason for lacking the tag on site. At the moment, let's think more about the alternative tag titles and let's choose the best tag for the mentioned purpose. We can think and choose the best tag for such purpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks, Aubrey - that's a very good idea!  I'm surprised actually that we didn't already have such a tag.  To get it started, I have tagged a few of the wikipedia-mentioning articles and submitted a tag wiki entry for review.

Comment: Thanks you! Let me now when it's ready :-)

Comment: I believe that you should be able to start making tag edits now; they will then go into the approval queue.  It's good to not flood too many in at a time, though, so that other things aren't knocked off the front page.